Triangle existence problem

Given two segments $AC$ and $BC$ and an angle $B$, it's possible to build only one triangle that has sides $AC$ and $BC$ when:
a) $AC > BC$
b) $B < \frac{\pi}{2}$
c) $AC < BC$
d) $AC = \frac{BC}{2}$

The book says the right answer is (a).
I got (c):

That's what I found: Since the problem only gave us $AC$ and $BC$ (and angle $B$) then $AB$ isn't fixed. Since a circle only intersects a line on $2$ points then if we trace $A_1 C$ then there's only one point $A_2$ from which $A_2 C$ is congruent to $A_1 C$. Then we have the isosceles triangle $A_1 C A_2$ from which $x > y$ (since $x = y + z$ and $z > 0$) and we also have that $y > b$ (if we trace a parallel line to $BC$ passing through $A_1$ then it's clear that $y > b$). If $y > b$ and $x > y$ then $x > b$, so $BC$ must be bigger than $A_1 C$, yet that's not the book's answer. I'm afraid I misunderstood the problem's statement.
Edit: I think that the problem asks for the condition necessary from which only one triangle must exist upon this condition, which could be AC > BC (But there's a problem). Have a look:

Note that if R = AC < BC then there will be no intersection between the circumference and AB. But however note that this doesn't excludes the case where AC = BC:

Since a angle only has two rays then there will be only one triangle: This also satisfies the problem's statement...

I do not completely follow your attempt, but it seems that you showed a situation where two triangles are possible. The question is asking about when the triangle is unique.

$AC > BC$ is not necessary for a single triangle to exist (and the question and the given answer do not claim that - see my answer for other cases where the triangle is unique). It is, however, sufficient.

Specifically, if $AC = BC$, then indeed the triangle is unique as well. In fact, the triangle is also unique in a specific case where $AC < BC$: namely, when $AC = BC \sin B$.

I find it easiest to see the conditions under which $0$, $1$, or $2$ triangles are possible with the Law of Cosines. For angle $B$, we have
$$AC^2 = BC^2 + AB^2 - 2 (BC) (AB) \cos B$$
We want to solve for the unknown side $AB$. This is just a quadratic:
$$AB^2 - (2 BC \cos B) AB + (BC^2 - AC^2) = 0$$
The discriminant is
$$\Delta = 4 BC^2 \cos^2 B - 4 (BC^2 - AC^2) = 4 AC^2 - 4 BC^2 (1 - \cos^2 B)$$
$$= 4 \left( AC^2 - (BC \sin B)^2 \right)$$
The roots of the equation are
$$AB = BC \cos B \pm \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\Delta}$$
If $AC < BC \sin B$ (i.e., $AC$ is sufficiently small), then $\Delta < 0$, and no such triangles exist.
If $AC = BC \sin B$, then $\Delta = 0$, and a unique triangle exists (it is a right triangle with $\angle A = \frac{\pi}{2}$).
If $BC \sin B < AC < BC$, then $\Delta > 0$ and $\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\Delta} < BC \cos B$. Therefore, two triangles are possible, one with $\angle A$ acute, and the other with $\angle A$ obtuse.
Finally, if $AC \ge BC$, then $\Delta > 0$ but $\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\Delta} \ge BC \cos B$. Therefore, a unique triangle exists (note that $AB$ must be positive).
So, the textbook is correct that $AC > BC$ implies a unique triangle exists.

Thanks! But i'm still confused, could you read the edit i wrote on the post?

The thing not to be overlooked in question is "only one triangle".
Off course in (c) BC > AC, two triangles A1BC and A2BC are possible. So will be the case with options D and B(B contains both cases with two triangles and only one triangle).
But with option (A), if we extend AC greater than BC, the radius of circle will be greater than BC/2, point A2 will be formed below BC. So it's one angle given as B (fixed) will not account. Hence it will build only one triangle. I have attached diagram reference for this.
Hope it clears!
Diagram
Answer to edit: When question is of MCQ form, you don't prove the option to be wrong or containing less information. You just have to pick if 'the option' satisfies condition of question.

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
